# Can I install windows at the end of the disk to avoid weak sectors located at the beginning?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, freeze

Two years ago, I bought an HP Probook 450 G2 i7, 15.6, with a 1 TB Toshiba MQ01ABD100 drive. Never had any problems with it till recently Windows 10 keeps freezing. Many times I formatted and started from scratch. As soon as all the programs are installed the system starts freezing from time to time. I only realized there is a problem with the drive when bootable Acronis gave the error of being unable to read data from a sector while it was making a system image. I analyzed it using HDD Regenerator 2011 from boot. Using the scan and repair option (around 4 hours), it reported no bad sectors but around 40 delays detected (slow sectors). Using a more in-depth scan (Mode Range), it reported 4411 "delays detected" (in roughly the same spots) and 0 bad sectors. According to the first and second scan, the delays are located mostly in the first half of the disk. The last quarter or so is totally free of errors.

The software claims it has repaired, or "regenerated," them, but I think it would be safer if I put the system in the still originally healthy portion of the disk and put the other data in the rest. As long as the system (C drive) is working smoothly with no freezing, I don't care if reading/writing non-system data from the other drives gets slow. I'm backing up all the important data daily and even online cloud backup second by second (for the most critical data), and I can afford a sudden disk death. I want to keep using the disk for some 6 or 9 months more (as long as the system does not freeze). (For personal reasons, I don't want to buy a new one now, but if you think I MUST change the drive NOW, I will, though it'll make life harder).

Please, is it possible to install windows at a partition at the end of the disk to avoid weak sectors located at the beginning by choosing the last partition in boot installation menu, for example? Or must the system be located at the first partition/portion? Below is a photo of HDD Regenerator, which continued with no more errors. It took about 50 hours.
Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no restrictions on where you have to install OS. First partition is just a convention. However, Windows may automatically place its boot files on the first partition. What's more, some partition table structures have their fixed location at the beginning of hard disk and there's nothing you can do about it.

If the damaged sectors were packed closely and first sectors were fine, I'd just leave the faulty area unpartitioned (to avoid putting any data there whatsoever) and proceed with installing Windows to the first partition. However, in your case problematic sectors are so scattered that reasonable partitioning seems impossible.

Using the continuous part at the end of the disk for OS partition seems like the best idea. It may not fix the lockups, though - after all, if the disk is stuck waiting for data partition, it may still not be able to read from OS partition.

And finally, **be aware that this HDD is a ticking time bomb**. It can only be used for data that you can afford to loose. Disks tend to go down without warning and degrade quickly once pending/bad sectors start to appear.

Comment: Please, are pending sectors the same as what HDD Regenerator calls "delays"? And since you are using a slash between "pending/bad sectors," do you think they are the same thing or equally bad? The software makes it clear that they are not the same and marks "bad sector" with a red color. It speaks about "delays" here: https://hddregenerator.net/wp_super_faq/what-is-it-delays-and-how-to-repair-delays/
Thanks.

Comment: @EasternRiver - HDD Regenerator might be excellent software but don't read to much into the marketing lingo.  Hard to take software seriously when the website which explains what it means by delays uses broken English.  "Permanent delays shows that your hdd has sectors with long access time." - So in other words, a sector with long access times, is a bad sectors.  You can put lipstick on a pig, but at the end of the day, it's still a pig.

Comment: I have considered using HDD Regenerator, until I read stuff like, ""The True About HDD Regenerator" which makes me question their ability to put out quality software.

Comment: @EasternRiver, as Ramhound noted, HDD Regenerator uses confusing wording. Bad sectors are usually automatically dealt with by the HDD - it silently remaps them to spare sectors, leaving only an increased [SMART parameter](https://kb.acronis.com/content/9105). [Pending sectors](https://kb.acronis.com/content/9133) are bad sectors waiting to be remapped.